# Long Decimal Number: Extract the ARGB values individually

Tags: javascript, html, flash

**I have colour values from a Flash application that are ARGB format(A being the alpha/transparency value).**

I have to convert that long decimal number to a RGB/Hexadecimal number in Javascript.

Do you know how I can extract the individual R, G, B & A values from a long(8 digit) number?

Here's my function which converts a number to hexadecimal BUT its not good enough because it needs to convert the values individually(R,G,B,A):

```
  function decimalToHex( num )
  {
     if (num == null || num == "undefined") { return "#FFFFFF"; }

     var intNum = (parseInt(num,10)) & 0x00FFFFFF;
     var strNum = intNum.toString(16);

     while (strNum.length <6) { strNum = "0"+strNum; }

     return "#"+strNum;  //+intNum.toString(16);
  }

  function getR( num )
  {
     // eg value for num is 84545883
     return (parseInt(num,10)) & 0x00FF0000;  // does this correctly get the R value from a ARGB value?
  }

  function getG( num )
  {
     // eg value for num is 84545883
     return (parseInt(num,10)) & 0x0000FF00;  // does this correctly get the G value from a ARGB value?
  }

  function getB( num )
  {
     // eg value for num is 84545883
     return (parseInt(num,10)) & 0x000000FF;  // does this correctly get the B value from a ARGB value?
  }
```

Comment: I believe you just need to shift over the A, R, and G values by the corresponding number of bits. You are on the right track by using a mask though. B does not require shifting because it is already the least significant value.

Answer (score 0):

Use match:

```
var argb = '12345678';
var bits = argb.match(/\d\d/g);

alert(bits);  // ['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

Now the bits are in an array that you can convert to hex and concatenate to get the hex RGB value. If the original was actually decimal values, then likely 3 characters are allowed for each value (000 to 255) and you might need:

```
var argb= '000101234034'
var bits = argb.match(/\d\d\d/g); // ['000', '101', '234', '034']
```

Comment: Why do you care about bits? The original number must be Type number or string - if it's a number it must be converted to a string. The output must be Type string. **Please** post some example data, fishing in the dark is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/36-uint-to-6-digit-rgb-hex-actionscript-30-as3) helps you.